# Which header do I need to include for DualTVL1OpticalFlow?

Tags: c++, opencv

Whenever I compile my code the error below occurs.

```
tvl1.cpp:36:13: error: no member named 'DualTVL1OpticalFlow' in namespace 'cv'
```

This is the offending line in my code.

```
Ptr<cv::DualTVL1OpticalFlow> tvCalc_ = createOptFlow_DualTVL1();
```

These are the header files I have included so far after reading the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/d47/classcv_1_1DualTVL1OpticalFlow.html).

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create the DualTVL1OpticalFlow pointer after including the `video.hpp` file:

```
#include "opencv2/video.hpp"
...
Ptr<cv::DualTVL1OpticalFlow> tvl1 = cv::DualTVL1OpticalFlow::create();
```